# Error al correr un Modulo llamado 'matplotlib'

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, vscode

Wstoy tratando de correr un codigo que baje de Github de >>> Soporte vectorial <<<. Pero al correrlo me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: Error]

Estoy Trabajando con Python 3 en Visual Studio Code instalado en Ubuntu 18.04

A continuación el enlace del Repositorio en GitHub y una captura del error.

Comment: Has probado a instalarlo? vía apt: `sudo apt install python3-matplotlib` y vía pip o pip3 : `pip3 install matplotlib`

Comment: No tienes instalado matplotlib. Tienes como mínimo tres formas de instalarlo: Usando el gestor de paquetes de Ubuntu (`apt install`), usando el gestor de paquetes de python (`pip install matplotlib`) o usando otra distribución de python llamada `anaconda`. Te recomiendo la última, pues tendrás acceso a la última versión de python (3.7) y a multitud de paquetes para ciencia de datos (matplotlib, pandas, numpy y muchos más), a la vez que no interferirás con la versión de python preinstalada en el sisteama. Visual Studio te dejará elegir cuál quieres usar.